# Subdomain "www" not working

Tags: apache, subdomain, config, vhosts

**Hi there!**

I'm trying to set up (two) Domains on a root server.

The problem I got is, that a subdomain with `www` in it, doesn't work.

So:

- www.domain.de
- name.bla.bla.domain.de
- domain.de

work.

But:

- name.www.domain.de

doesn't work.

My `domain.de` DNS-Zone is also set to `*.domain.de`, so this should work.

Here is my vHost for this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName name.www.domain.de
    ServerAlias name.domain.de
    #ServerAlias name.bla.bla.domain.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/some/folder/here
    ServerAdmin me@domain.de
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache doesn't throw any errors when reloading.

Can you help me?

Comment: Weird. What does httpd -S gives you ? And what about ping name.www.domain.de ? I never saw this case before, maybe there's a particular control about 'www' string in domains.

Comment: do you have another virtual host defined? if yes, and it comes before this VH (in search order) and also matches the name (wildcard?), then possibly the request is handled by that VH

Comment: @OlivierH : httpd = apache2 ? I'm on Debian, if this matters. It shows me `apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}`. A ping couldn't find host.

@Eternal-Learner : I now got 4 vHosts (and yes, with Wildcards). But why would `name.bla.bla.domain.de` work then?

Comment: `httpd` is a program : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html. `-S` option displays parsed virtualhosts. Also look into your apache2 logs, maybe a notice or warning is thrown at apache's starting.

Comment: And maybe try to set your DNS-ZONE to `*.www.domain.de` too.

Comment: Can't find any useful things in the logs. Apache just claims, that there isn't a favicon.ico and robots.txt in there.
@OlivierH My system can't find `httpd` as a program.

Comment: @SebastianGnich Oh sorry, this binary is not included in std apache 2 Debian packages. You can use `apache2ctl` instead : `apache2ctl -S`

Comment: @OlivierH Nice, thanks. It shows me my 4 vHosts I got, that's good. Syntax is also OK. Isn't there something like a Debug-Mode, where I can see what each line does?

Comment: You can try `apache2ctl configtest`

Comment: It also says just `Syntax OK`. The only thing I don't understand is `name.www.domain1.de:80 ::1 - - [13/Nov/2013:14:04:12 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) (internal dummy connection)"`. Maybe you know what it means?

Comment: That is so strange.. `name.bla.bla.bla.domain.de` works, but a simple `www` doesn't.. I can ping this host from the server itself, so it is not accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer.

Sometimes it isn't enough just to `reload` Apache, instead of `restart`ing it.

Thank you very much for your help!